# Id and global Variable

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, How element objects are thrown on calling the id ?
I am little surprised and confused about this behaviour.

**Example:**

```
<input type="hidden" value="test" id="idtest">
```

When I call "idtest", it returns the whole object.

It is behaviouring the same for all id elements not only for input elements.

When I use the global variable same as "idtest", It will cause an issue with global variables.

How it is working ?

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: You can't. It was a stupid feature of Internet Explorer which has now been stupidly standardized -- we have to live with it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi True that.

Comment: "When I use the global variable same as "idtest", It will cause an issue with global variables." — Another reason to minimise the use of global variables. Creating a local scope for each program in an IIFE is usually a good idea.